# ransack filter criteria dropdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I use the current version of Ransack gem with Rails 5 and MySQL and want to implement a search form where I can have two select fields:

1) first dropdown select list should contain the table column attributes eg. first_name, last_name, street

2) second dropdown select list should contain the operator like "equals", "is not", "contains"

and then an input field for the search keyword and a submit button.

In code it should look something like this:

```
<%= search_form_for @search do |f| %>
  <%= f.select :select_criteria, options_for_select([
        ['first name', :first_name], 
        ['last name', :last_name], 
        ['street', :street]
        ]), @search.select_criteria %>
  <%= f.select :operator, options_for_select([
      ['contains', :contains], 
      ['is not', :is_not], 
      ['equals', :equals]
      ]), @search.operator %>
  <%= f.search_field :term %>
  <%= f.submit "filter" %>
<% end %>
```

But I can't find any examples in the ransack documentation that covers this case.

How does it look correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this. I've used this in an application. This uses the technique shown in the ransack demo app.

```
<%= search_form_for @search do |f| %>
  <%= f.grouping_fields(f.object.new_grouping) do |g| %>
    <%= g.condition_fields(g.object.new_condition) do |c| %>
      <%= c.attribute_fields do |a| %>
        <%= a.attribute_select only: %i(id) %>
      <% end %>
      <%= c.predicate_select only: %i(cont not_eq eq) %>
      <%= c.value_fields do |v| %>
        <%= v.text_field :value %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit "filter" %>
<% end %>
```

Ransack can take a group of conditions and search by them all at once. In your case, you can supply one group with one condition. I know this seems fairly verbose, but I'm not sure of a simpler approach with ransack (there could be one though).

I'd say the key lines here are `f.grouping_fields(f.object.new_grouping)` and `g.condition_fields(g.object.new_condition)`. These work like `fields_for` in that you need to have at least one grouping setup for the block to render anything.

You can read the full documentation about predicates [here](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/blob/master/lib/ransack/constants.rb). These values can be provided to the `only` option in `c.predicate_select`. You can also build [custom predicates](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/wiki/Custom-Predicates) fairly easily if you need them.

A good source of documentation for ransack is the [ransack demo app](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack_demo). For example, here's [how they build an advanced search form](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack_demo/blob/master/app/views/users/advanced_search.erb). You can also look at the [live demo of advanced search](http://ransack-demo.herokuapp.com/users/advanced_search).

Here's a screenshot of the advanced search demo. It looks relatively similar to what you're trying to achieve.

[image: Example of ransack advanced search]

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works great but in <%= a.attribute_select only: %i(id) %> 
 the "only :id" statement seems to be ignored. in the select dropdown list all attributes are available. Do you know how to allow only first_name, last_name and street as values for the drop down list?

Comment: @Trinity76 ah, you're right. I was wondering about that. One way you can do it is by defining a `ransackable_attributes` method on your model (https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack#authorization-whitelistingblacklisting). This would be a global change for all ransack searches on that model though.